# Cartesian product of two graphs

Tags: graph-theory

How can I show that the number of edges of the Cartesian product of two graphs may be a prime number?
Hadwiger number may be useful but I do not know how can I use it

Comment: Can you use a one-point graph as one of your two graphs?

Comment: yes ı can use it

Comment: Well, doesn't the Cartesian product of $K_1$ and $G$ have the same number of edges as $G$? (Unless I'm mixing up the Cartesian product with some other kind of graph product.) So why don't you just take one of the two graphs to be some graph with $p$ edges (where $p$ is your favorite prime number), and take $K_1$ for the other graph?

Answer (score 1):

It's always helpful to try some simple examples.
We can look at the graphs $P_3$, i.e. the path on 3 vertices with 2 edges, and $P_2 = K_2$, i.e. the path on 2 vertices with 1 edge. The cartesian product of $P_3$ and $P_2$ is the $3\times 2$ grid. This graph has $3\cdot 2 = 6$ vertices, and 3 horizontal and 4 vertical edges. So it has a total of 7 edges, and 7 is prime.

Comment: ı got it, so can you  give me an example for the number of edges of the conjunction of two graphs necessarily an even number.ı have a lot of question like that and ı try to find examples for these questions, this is the last one.

Comment: @anı "necessarily an even number" calls for a proof, not an example. Hint: does the conjunction of K_2 and K_2 has an even number of edges? Why is that?